# Crystal Reports (.NET) – API to set "Text Interpretation" property?

Tags: visual-studio, crystal-reports

Please help me to find way to programatically control field's *Text Interpretation* property. I am able to find access to other properties shown on the *Paragraph* tab in report designer, but I'm unable to find access to this one.

My intention is to set *Text Interpretation* property in the runtime either to *Uninterpreted* or *HTML* based on content of incoming data.

[image: Right-click Field > click Format Object > click 'Paragraph' tab. Yellow highlightset added.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a formula since the 'Text Interpretation' is ONLY a property of these fields:

Database
Formula
Parameter
Group Name

Comment: I know I can use a formula. But Crystal Report properties cannot be changed programatically? I admit I do not understand this aspect of Crystal Reports yet. Does *property* mean it can be set only during design time? And also: is it possible to set the formula programatically during the runtime? (I would like to avoid design-time formulae.)

Comment: You have to create a formula to represent your text field since you can't set the property directly to the field. So create a formula "textToFormula". In that formula you put your text field {text.field}. Put the formula into the report, then right-click on it, choose "Format" and you should be able to set the text interpretation.

Comment: Ok, then I will use either your approach or I will switch the field permanently to HTML (and will display plain text there after conversion of `<`, `>`, `&`, ...) or I will use 2 overlapping fields, one for plain text, one for HTML. One additional question: is it possible to create field (with correctly set *Text Interpretation*) during the runtime?

Comment: Yes, you can approach it several different ways. Good luck and please remember to mark answers accordingly if they helped you or answered your question.

Comment: Sure, I'm always marking the answers when the question is concluded. Thank you for answering.

Comment: No problem, I wasn't implying anything, just a friendly reminder.

Comment: @Miroxlav, I never saw your first comment to my answer. I apologize for that. Please let me know if you have any more issues even though you marked my answer as correct which leads me to believe you solved the problem.

Comment: Due to very limited HTML support even if *Text Interpretation* is switched to *HTML* I finally abandoned the idea of rendering the HTML content using Crystal Reports. If I'll need it badly, then I'll render HTML into images elsewhere and pass the resulting images into Crystal Reports.